# jQuery UI autocomplete values in a horizontal list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI autocomplete. I exactly copied the simple example from the jQuery UI website https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

```
<head>     
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [ 'some values here' ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The functionality is working. But for some reason, my values are displayed in a ugly box with values next to each other.

[image: my screenshot]

I want the values in the nice vertical list that you can see on the jQuery UI website.

[image: jquery]

I don't think it's a CSS issue because even if I remove all styles from my webpage, it still looks the same.

Any idea why is it broken on my side? How can I get the nice horizontal list?

Comment: Do you mean you remove **all** CSS, even your own CSS files, everything inline, etc, and it is still horizontal?  The appearance is 100% controlled by CSS, so my guess is some other style on the page is conflicting.  [Here's a JSFiddle of your code and tags](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/qc9xprv7/), where I simply override `ul` and `li` styling to "break" formatting to match what you are seeing.  Is it possible some other CSS on your page is doing that, or similar?

Comment: Yes, I am also not able to reproduce the issue in a sandbox environment. This must have to with your local code. Try to create a simple HTML page in your app and see if you can reproduce the issue.

Comment: You were right. I tried sandbox environment and wasn't able to reproduce the issue. Which lead me to investigating the css and finding out that this is actually controlled by the formatting of the <ul> and <li> elements instead of the <input> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of the suggestions is completely controlled by CSS.  If you have some styles of your own on the page which, for example, style `ul` and `li`, that can cause *exactly* the layout problem you are seeing.

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/qc9xprv7/), using exactly the same code as you, and with the tags from your screenshot, demonstrating that.  In fact it only needs to style `li` to create what you see.

There must be some similar CSS applied on your page which is conflicting and overriding with jQuery UI's own styling of that suggestion list.  You can find it by typing a single letter to generate the suggestions, then opening your browser's devtools, and finding the generated `ul` - it will have a class `ui-autocomplete`.  Disable the `display: none` style, to make sure it is displayed:

[image]

Now click the `li` elements, and inspect the styling.

In my example JSFiddle, you can see what is causing the problem by toggling on/off the `display: inline-block;` to see how it affects the suggestions list:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in the `<input>` element as one might expect. jQuery takes the provided list and transforms it into html `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. Therefore once you remove the css formatting for these elements, the autocomplete list will start displaying properly.